# Favorite tag color

Tags: feature-request, tags

I searched a bit to see if this had been asked before, but couldn't find it. Is there a way to customize the color that a question is shaded when it is tagged with one of my "favorite tags?"

Maybe it is just me, but when I scroll down through the front page of questions, the shading is so light that I often miss them. I find this shading color infuriating. I often tilt my laptop to an absurd angle just so I can tell which ones are shaded.

Comment: More on faint colors: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1117/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on clicking links from the links everyone else provided, I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66592/define-your-own-color-of-tagged-interesting) accepted answer to be the only thing that actually helped me change it. I'm essentially CSS illiterate, so I needed it spelled out a little more thoroughly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this directly on the site, but you can do it using a user style sheet, which requires a browser extension like Stylish (for Firefox at least). You would need to set the `background-color` property for the `tagged-interesting` CSS class.

This has been discussed a bit on MSO, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78849/allow-custom-colorization-of-tags) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68853/choose-background-and-text-color-on-so).